# How to make full size horizontal scroll pages?

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

The code below shows a few divs with the class name `page`, each having a height of `100vh` whilst displaying some text within.

I want the scrolling to be horizontal rather than vertical, how do I get this to work?

HTML:

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="page">Page 1</div>
  <div class="page">Page 2</div>
  <div class="page">Page 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: you'd need to make your container wider than the display port.

Comment: You are missing a few things: https://fiddle.jshell.net/5h0xj9hz/. I would change the `100vh` for `100%` because vh causes the vertical overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Horizontal scroll with each page covers the entire viewport.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.all {
  font-size: 0; /*remove white space*/
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.page {
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font size*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.page:nth-child(1) {
  background: pink;
}
.page:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.page:nth-child(3) {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="page">Page 1</div>
  <div class="page">Page 2</div>
  <div class="page">Page 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add float: left;, i think it should work

```
.all {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
float: left;
}

.page {
height: 100vh;
position: relative;
display: inline-block
}
```